# A simple way to find out if all array values are empty?

Tags: php

Is there a simpler way than this?

```
$isArrayEmpty = true;
foreach ($array as $value) {
    if (!empty($value)) {
        $isArrayEmpty  = false;
    }
}
```

Seems kinda redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, it's not redundant. it's perfectly legitimate way. nothing bad in this code. just add `break` to it.

I'd even say your current approach is the best one, just keep it.
For frequent use you can wrap it in a function

Answer (score 6):

<del>`$isArrayEmpty = empty( array_filter( $array ) );`</del>

**Edit**
As noted in the comments the above expression will not work - it will throw a fatal error. This is because `empty` can only operate on variables and not the return value of a function (or language construct)

So as etarion suggested the correct answer in the same spirit of my answer is:

```
$isArrayEmpty = !array_filter( $array );
```

Comment: When I see such a code in some file, I'll be puzzled what does it do. Write-only code is disgusting

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel: Well, you will never see it, because it won't work. `empty` operates on variables, not expressions. However, `$isArrayEmpty = ! array_filter( $array );` is perfectly valid and if you're puzzled what it does, you should probably look up what array_filter does, because it is made _for this exact purpose_.

Comment: wow, yeah - I just tried running this code and got a fatal error. Wrong!

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel Although it doesn't work (as per comment), in what way is it "write only"? etarions example looks perfectly sane, 'cept for those crazy PHP sigils ;-) Once "functional-like" constructs are learned (e.g. filter, map/flatmap, and fold) they can greatly simplify a good number of operations over collections.

Comment: @pst yes, write-only it is. will simplify writing and make reading hard as hell. perl is a king in such "simplifications"

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way of doing it using [`array_reduce`](http://php.net/array_reduce):

```
$isArrayEmpty = array_reduce($array, function($acc, $e) { return $acc && empty($e); }, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$foo = implode('', $array);
$isArrayEmpty = empty($foo);
```

Answer (score -1):

Can't you just...

```
if(empty($array)) {  //do this  }
```

Comment: That will only check if the $array variable is empty not if each item in the array is empty.  Its a differnt thing.